# How to pass a unique_ptr to set the member variable of my object?

Tags: c++, oop, pointers, inheritance

I'm writing a chess application. The `Board` class contains an array of `Square`, each of which can hold a `Piece`. Type-specific classes (`Pawn`, `Rook`, etc.) inherit from `Piece`.

In order to accomplish this, `Square` has a member variable which points to a particular `Piece` (which is occupying that `Square`).

The trouble I'm having is that when I try to set up the `Board`, I am unable to assign the `unique_ptr` that I've created to the member variable of the `Square`.

Here's the general stream of function calls:

```
void Board::setBoard()
{
    // White Pawn Placement
    std::unique_ptr<Piece> wp1 = std::make_unique<Pawn>(PAWN, WHITE);
    Board::setPiece("a2", wp1);
}
```

↓

```
Pawn::Pawn(Type t, Color c) : Piece(t, c) {}
```

↓

```
void Board::setPiece(const std::string &coords, std::unique_ptr<Piece> piece)
{
    squareMap[coords].setPiece(piece);
}
```

↓

```
void Square::setPiece(std::unique_ptr<Piece> piece)
{
    Square::piece = std::move(piece);
}
```

I receive the following error when I attempt to compile at the line holding `Board::setPiece("a2", wp1);`

```
error: call to implicitly-deleted copy constructor of 'std::unique_ptr<Piece>'
```

which is, needless to say, a bit of a mouthful.

There is some good documentation online about inheritance, abstract classes, how to use the `unique_ptr`, etc., but I've been unable to figure out how all of those things fit together.

So, the question:

**How can I create an object, assign it to a unique_ptr, and then use that unique_ptr to set the member variable of another object?**

Here are the header files for each class, in case that is illuminating. And please forgive the length of my question. I've made it as short as I can.

**Board.hpp**

```
class Board {
public:
    Board();
    void printBoard();
    Piece getPiece(const std::string &coords);
    void setPiece(const std::string &coords, std::unique_ptr<Piece> piece);
    ~Board();
    ...
};
```

**Square.hpp**

```
class Square
{
public:
    void setPiece(std::unique_ptr<Piece> piece);
    Piece* getPiece() const;
protected:
    std::unique_ptr<Piece> piece;
    ...
};
```

**Piece.hpp**

```
class Piece
{
public:
    Piece();
    Piece(Type, Color);
    virtual bool movePiece() = 0; // abstract class
protected:
    Color color;
    Type type;
    bool moved;
    ...
};
```

**Pawn.hpp**

```
class Pawn : public Piece
{
public:
    Pawn(Type t, Color c);
    bool movePiece() override;
};
```

Comment: Why is `piece` a pointer?

Comment: It's my understanding that in order for Square to hold different sub-classes of Piece, it has to be set up as a pointer to the base class.

Comment: `std::move`ing a `std::unique_ptr<T>` gives you a `std::unique_ptr<T>&&` not a `T*`. Sounds like `piece` should be a `std::unique_ptr<Piece> piece;` and the setter changed accordingly.

Comment: Ah, yes, sorry.  I missed that you are deriving from it.  Why not use a `std::unique_ptr<Piece>` in square then?

Comment: @NathanOliver Good question. I've tried that, but it causes problems elsewhere. I think part of my problem is misunderstanding where I need to be using raw pointers and where I need to be using a `unique_ptr`.

Comment: Use raw pointer when ownership is not being passed (but could be nullptr).  Use unique_ptr when ownership is being handed off.  Use reference when ownership is not being passed, and cannot be nullptr.

Comment: You want to use `unique_ptr` when the object needs to control the lifetime of the pointer.  You use regular pointers when you are just observing the thing, not actually managing its lifetime.

Comment: @NathanOliver @Eljay If I switch to passing `unique_ptr` into `Board::setPiece()` and `Square::setPiece()`, the compiler error transforms to `error: call to implicitly-deleted copy constructor of 'std::unique_ptr<Piece>'`. Should I be passing a reference to this pointer instead?

Comment: @AlexJohnson When you intend on passing ownership over, if you have an lvalue (essentially a named object) you need to `std::move` it or it will try to copy it. You cannot copy a `unique_ptr` which is what makes it unique.

Comment: @AlexJohnson You have two choices: 1) make `Square` **own** the `Piece` that is currently on it, and then `move()` that `unique_ptr` around as the `Piece` moves around the `Board`. Or 2) make the `Board` **own** all of the active `Piece`s, such as in a `std::vector` or `std::array`, and then simply pass around raw `Piece*` pointers to each `Square` as needed since they won't **own** each `Piece`. You need to define your ownership rules.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux That makes sense. When I update `Square::setPiece()` to `Square::piece = std::move(piece);` the issue described above (`call to implicitly-deleted copy constructor...`) remains.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Thank you. The model I am aiming for is the square owning the piece that's on it.

Comment: @AlexJohnson then you must declare `Square::piece` to be `std::unique_ptr<Piece>` instead of `Piece*`, and change your setter to match. Otherwise, do not use `std::unique_ptr` at all, and have `~Square()` manually `delete` the `Piece` when it is no longer needed (captured, etc).

Comment: @RemyLebeau That's where I'm at currently. Just still struggling with the `implicitly-deleted` error message.

Comment: @AlexJohnson then please update your question with your latest code, and indicate WHERE the error is occurring. You are clearly still doing something wrong. You are trying to perform a copy where a move is required (if I had to guess, probaby in your `getPiece()` methods - you might need to switch to `std::shared_ptr<Piece>` instead, depending on HOW you use `getPiece()`)

Comment: @AlexJohnson well, after your update, now you omitted `std::move()` calls that are needed. You are passing `std::unique_ptr` objects around **by value**, so you need to `move()` them. I think you need to stop what you are doing and go read up on how `unique_ptr` actually works

Comment: @RemyLebeau Apologies. Updated. The error occurs at the lines `Board::setPiece("a2", wp1);` and `squareMap[coords].setPiece(piece);`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187956/discussion-between-alex-johnson-and-remy-lebeau).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is you are passing around `std::unique_ptr` objects **by value** without the use of `std::move()`, so you are trying to **copy** them instead of **move** them.  `std::unique_ptr` cannot be copied from, only moved from, otherwise single-ownership semantics would be broken. That is what makes `std::unique_ptr` "unique" - only 1 `std::unique_ptr` at a time can refer to a given object in memory.

Try something more like this instead:

```
class Pawn : public Piece
{
public:
    Pawn(Color c);
    ...
};
```

```
Pawn::Pawn(Color c) : Piece(PAWN, c) {}
```

```
class Square
{
public:
    ...

    // for accessing the current Piece without moving it around the Board
    // (for printing, drawing, etc)...
    const Piece* getPiece() const;

    // for moving Pieces around the Board...
    std::unique_ptr<Piece> setPiece(std::unique_ptr<Piece> piece);

    ...

protected:
    std::unique_ptr<Piece> piece;
    ...
};
```

```
const Piece* Square::getPiece() const
{
    return piece.get();
}

std::unique_ptr<Piece> Square::setPiece(std::unique_ptr<Piece> piece)
{
    std::unique_ptr<Piece> old = std::move(this->piece);
    this->piece = std::move(piece);
    return std::move(old);
}
```

```
class Board {
public:
    ...

    // for accessing a current Piece without moving it around the Board
    // (for printing, drawing, etc)...
    const Piece* getPiece(const std::string &coords) const;

    // for moving Pieces around the Board...
    std::unique_ptr<Piece> setPiece(const std::string &coords, std::unique_ptr<Piece> piece);

    ...

protected:
    std::map<std::string, Square> squareMap;
    ...
};
```

```
void Board::setBoard()
{
    ...

    // White Pawn Placement
    std::unique_ptr<Piece> wp1 = std::make_unique<Pawn>(WHITE);
    setPiece("a2", std::move(wp1));

    // or simply:
    //setPiece("a2", std::make_unique<Pawn>(WHITE));

    ...
}

const Piece* Board::getPiece(const std::string &coords) const
{
    auto iter = squareMap.find(coords);
    return (iter != squareMap.end())
        ? iter->second.getPiece()
        : nullptr;
}

std::unique_ptr<Piece> Board::setPiece(const std::string &coords, std::unique_ptr<Piece> piece)
{
    return squareMap[coords].setPiece(std::move(piece));
}
```

This allows `Square` to maintain **ownership** of whatever `Piece` is currently assigned to it, and that ownership is **transferred** only when a new `Piece` is assigned (for instance, to move a captured `Piece` to another list, to be reclaimed when a `Pawn` gets promoted).

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to help with this. Quick follow up: How would you handle the event that you try to get a piece from a square that doesn't contain one (i.e., in `Square::getPiece()`)?

Comment: Also, why would you return a `std::unique_ptr<Piece>` from `Square::setPiece()`?

Comment: I suppose the core of my questions above is how one would go about moving a piece if `Board::getPiece()` and `Square::getPiece()` both return a `const` pointer. Obviously I could change the signatures, but I want to make sure what I'm doing is the correct thing to do. I understand that you had tagged those functions as being related to printing, drawing, etc. Just want to be sure that I'm understanding your thoughts well.

Comment: I've found that a `Board::movePiece(fromCoords, toCoords)` function which implements a single line like this `setPiece(toCoords, setPiece(fromCoords, nullptr));` works to move a piece around the board. Was that your original intent?

Comment: @AlexJohnson actually, dealing with captured pieces was my *original* intent for having `setPiece()` return the `Piece` being replaced, to avoid having to implement separate `removePiece()` methods. But your `movePiece()` example is another good use for it, too

Comment: Noted. Thank you again for all of your guidance.