# How to extend a C++ structure/class with a void `null` or `empty` like element

Tags: c++, data-structures

I am implementing a chess module as I learn C++.  In the module I have (partially) implemented:

- a `Board` class (grid, pieces, move methods etc.)
- enumerated types `Colour` (BLACK/WHITE) and `Rank` (KING, QUEEN, ..., PAWN)

and

- a `Piece` structure grouping colour and rank (BLACK KING,..., WHITE PAWN).

I am now deciding how to represent the contents of a square on the board (grid). A square must either contain a `Piece` (BLACK KING), or nothing. Options considered:

- create a `struct Square` containing two data members, `{bool occupied ; Piece piece;}`, (possibly extending the `Piece` class).

  MY OBJECTION: Solution seems a little too heavy-weight, and in the event that the square is not occupied then the `piece` member should be empty. I feel it may lead to exceptions being needed for some class methods, which should not be necessary.
- extending the enumeration of `Rank` or `Colour` to include an empty option.

  MY OBJECTION: Feels semantically inelegant, hacky and unnatural.
- looking into other packages like `std::optional`

  MY OBJECTION: For coding style and simplicity, I'd like to avoid the use of extra machinery. Would `std::optional` even be suitable?
- using `NULL` or `nullptr` to represent the state of an empty square

  MY OBJECTION: Again, seems hacky. The contents of an empty square are NOT `NULL`, nor the number `0`, should not be comparable to the number 26... but should be a fresh, new constant EMPTY_SQUARE.

None of these options quite seem to fit. Is there some more elegant way of extending a class (like `Piece`) with other members (like `EMPTY_SQUARE`) which has none of the original class's data members? (Are there any other options?)

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2537942/nullable-values-in-c and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7645578/best-way-to-represent-nullable-member-in-c

Comment: Why not create an interface class to represent the square content, and derive either a `Piece` or `Empty` class to define the content. Then your `Square` struct should hold a pointer to the interface. You can check which "child" class exist in the square later

Comment: Use `std::optional`, it's exactly the right tool. I don't understand your objection about "extra machinery" to that approach.

Comment: Related : [another chess app question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54543496/) trying to solve a similar problem.

Comment: This sounds pretty opinion based. Personally I would go for `nullptr` because either a square contains a piece or it doesn't. So it either points to a piece object or it doesn't. It is an easy test and feels unsurprising. I don't consider it "hackey" at all.

Comment: @NirMH are you suggesting to have a Square {...} class with a (public?) data member like bool contains_piece, and a derived class Occupied_square : Square {...}?  Will this create typecasting issues? ie. When a piece is moved from a square, the class of that square (`Occupied_square`) will be demoted to just a plain old `Square`.

Answer (score 4):

A square on your chess board can either contain a piece or be empty. In more abstract terms you want to have either some specific thing or nothing at all. **That’s exactly the use case `std::optional` is made for.** You cannot avoid extra machinery anyway because you need *something* to represent an empty square. In 2019-style C++ an optional type is a perfectly simple and idiomatic solution, especially when it comes from the standard library.

Regarding your other alternatives:

- `struct Square`: I agree with your objections, especially the question about what to put into the `piece` member when the square is empty. In short: `struct Square` is a naive, super-simple version of an optional.
- Extending the enums: I agree completely.
- `nullptr`: Sometimes a null pointer can be an appropriate representation of “nothing”. Usually you run into the issue when your implementation works with pointers anyway and you don’t want to introduce `std::optional<T*>` – that would introduce an additional nothing-ish state along with its ambiguity. In general I do agree about avoiding null pointers wherever possible.

Answer (score 0):

How about keeping a collection of none-empty squares?

```
typedef std::map<square,piece,chessboard_order,chessboard_allocator> chess_position;
```

Custome allocator is needed because no more than 64 squares are possible. Moreover the collection shrinks as the game proceeds, because pieces are taken.

Answer (score 0):

How about each figure have a position? And store a list of all the figures on the board.

The board would have the logic associated with verifying the rules of movement.

Comment: You mean something like storing 16 white and 16 black figures , each with 8 pawns (like <PAWN,WHITE, B1>,...), 2 bishops (<BISHOP,BLACK,C8>) etc. etc.? That would be an interesting way to design the implementation, but not really in the scope of the question.

Comment: As I see it, you're having a problem with representing an empty state. This way, the problem is non-existent.

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to introduce a `Null_Piece` ([Null Object Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_object_pattern))

What you will then need to do is create Base class `Piece` and classes which will implement the behaviors of the pieces `Pawn`, `Knight`, `Bishop`, `Rook`, `Queen`, and `King`.

`NullPiece` will implement the same behaviors, but instead there will be no action.

This way every `Square` on the board can have a piece.